# How to declare class variables as constants

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core

I am new to writing unit test files in .Net Core. I have a constant file where I need to create a list of objects for a class.

Below code is working.

```cs
public class user
{
    public const Int ID = "1";
    public const String Name = "FakeUserId1";
    public readonly List<access> p  = new List<access>(){
        new access {
            edit = true,
            edit = true,
            siteid = 123
        },
        new access {
            edit = true,
            edit = false,
            siteid = 234
        }
    };
}

public class access
{
    public Boolean edit;
    public Boolean delete;
    public int siteid;
}
```

Is it possible to declare access class variables as constants and initialize them in the list?

Something like this

```cs
public class access
{
  public const Boolean edit;
  public const  Boolean delete;
  public const int siteid;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean make an instance of `access` a constant or do you mean create a constant inside the `access` type?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const): "Constants can be numbers, Boolean values, strings, or a null reference" (*in case you were wanting to create an instance of `access` a constant*)

Comment: Edited my question to show what i am looking for. I mean I want to restrict creating an object to that class other then my list

Comment: A constant value is a compile time substitution of value. So what actually happens at compile time is that any where you reference `user.ID` in your code it will be replaced with `1` so if you look at the compiled IL code you will see `1` and not `user.ID` in those locations. Apply that to what you are now asking...

Comment: @Igor Thank you for your explanation. The documentation is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could mark the fields as `readonly`, and supply a constructor:

```
public class access
{
    public readonly Boolean edit;
    public readonly Boolean delete;
    public readonly int siteid;
    public access(Boolean e, Boolean d, int s)
    {
        edit = e;
        delete = d;
        sideid = s;
    }
}
```

And then in your `user` class:

```
public readonly List<access> p  = new List<access>(){
    new access(true, true, 123),
    new access(true, false, 234)
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked.I had to make the list static readonly in order to access it from other classes. If not, i am getting "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property" error.

Comment: @vanis if this answer solved your problem then please accept it to help others find the solution faster.